# How to send an inline image in Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm writing a python bot, and have this function, that is *supposed* to send an inline image, but it works strangely:

```
async def inline_catimg(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    print("Cat called, query: "+query)
    if not query:
        return
    print("Got past check")
    url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/A-Cat.jpg/2560px-A-Cat.jpg"
    #url = "https://files.fm/f/38gfdcbw9t"
    #url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/the-guy-bot/cats/main/our_cat_4.jpg"
    #url = "D:/Access/cat_nobg.png"

    results = []
    results.append(
        InlineQueryResultPhoto(
            id=query+time.time.__str__(),
            title='caps',
            photo_url=url,
            thumbnail_url=url
        )
    )
    await context.bot.answer_inline_query(update.inline_query.id, results)
```

I also run it like this, if it matters:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()

    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    inline_catimg_handler = InlineQueryHandler(inline_catimg)

    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    application.add_handler(inline_catimg_handler)

    unknown_handler = MessageHandler(filters.COMMAND, unknown)
    application.add_handler(unknown_handler)

    application.run_polling()
```

And I import those libraries:

```
import logging
import time

from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, InlineQueryResultPhoto, InputTextMessageContent, Update
from telegram.ext import filters, MessageHandler, InlineQueryHandler, ApplicationBuilder, ContextTypes, CommandHandler
import random
```

What I want this code to do:

Create an inline python bot, that, if you type ***"@BotName"*** in any chat, would show a list of commands that this bot can do. Like ***"Turn this text to caps"*** or ***"Send a cat image"***.

Then you click on one of them, and it replaces your message with something (like a cat image or your text but in caps), based on the command that you chose, and sends it (it says above ***"via BotName"***).

The problem is that if I type ***"@BotName something"*** in any chat, it doesn't show the commands list. It just says *"nothing here"* or something like that. Sometimes it does show an image of a cat that sends it if you click on it, though I couldn't find out why.

Also, I have a few links there, and none of them work exept for Wikimedia one.

How can I fix it? Does anyone know how this stuff works (I have no idea what I am doing)?

Appreciate any help, as I don't know much about all this stuff

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @СергейКох, clarified